# EF Query getting the Include operation for navigation not reachable warning

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple query

```
            clients = _context.Clients
               .Include(e => e.TrainerClients)
               .Include(e => e.User)
               .Where(e => e.TrainerClients.All(f => f.Status == UserStatus.Linked));
```

that returns:

[image]

but I get a warning message if executed as-is:

```
The Include operation for navigation '[e].User' is unnecessary and was ignored because the navigation is not reachable in the final query results.
```

However, if I comment out the Include(e => e.User) from the query, I don't get the warning, but I also don't get the User data.

[image]

So why am I getting this warning, and how can I refine my query to not get the warning?

UPDATE:
Client model:

```
public class Client : BaseModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }    
    public DateTime LastPaidDate { get; set; }
    public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TrainerClient> TrainerClients { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool Facebook { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LastLoginTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    //Properties Client used just for relation
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public ProfileSetting ProfileSetting { get; set; }
}
```

TrainerClient:

```
public class TrainerClient : BaseModel
{
    public int TrainerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TrainerId))]
    public Trainer Trainer { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ClientId))]
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public Enum.UserStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Enum.RequestType RequestType { get; set; }

    public string RequestDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have two tables 1)Users 2) Clients?  Then join the two tables by Id.

Comment: i have a clients table that has navigation properties to trainerclient and clients. i was under the impression if i just use include it pulls the data with the query, which is what i want...just dont want the warning. From this page https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Could you show us the model builder for your linking table?

Comment: Updated with models

Comment: How you finalize the query?

Comment: What do you mean finalize?

Comment: I think he means, how are you materializing this query? With `ToList()`? Or do you create an anonymous object? I experience the same behavior as you, I have no answer to this as well.

Comment: the client declared in the question is, IQueryable<Client> clients, hence the reason I don't do a ToList().